# MVC 3: Hide ID property using EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have this line in my View:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

And this is my ViewModel:

```
public class CommentForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Kommentar"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that `Id` renders as a textfield in the form. Actually, I only want to use `Id` in the form action. Is there an attribute that tells the editor not to render the property `Id`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for your contributions, but I didn't really like them.

I made my own PreventRenderingAttribute.

**PreventRenderingAttribute.cs**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PreventRenderingAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
        metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
    }
}
```

**And in CommentForm**

```
[PreventRendering]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 21):

Setting ShowForDisplay and ShowForEdit to false is already done by the standard

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

attribute.
Your custom attribute therefore seems like overkill.

Answer (score 15):

One possibility is to render it as a hidden field:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Another possibility is to write a custom editor template for your `CommentForm` view model and inside this template include whatever you want (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CommentForm.cshtml`):

```
@model CommentForm
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comment)
</div>
```

Comment: good work ;) i delete my answer and upvote yours. If not, we have two answers with the same content.

Comment: I solved it by making my own attribute, however I can't answer my question for another 7 hours :/ In short, I did something like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2010/06/11/custom-asp-net-mvc-2-modelmetadataprovider-for-using-custom-view-model-attributes.aspx