# Issues with ShowForDisplay/ShowForEdit using IMetadataAware in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

I have a viewmodel and need to create a means to hide certain properties of the view model from display or editing.  I am trying to implement a custom attribute that implements [IMetadataAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  I am basing my simple implementation from examples in the following SO questions:

- [MVC 3: Hide ID property using EditorForModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339114/mvc-3-hide-id-property-using-editorformodel/8353343)
- [Can I use an IMetadataAware attribute multiple times on the same
  field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220585/can-i-use-an-imetadataaware-attribute-multiple-times-on-the-same-field)
- [Can I show/hide a view model element with data annotations based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193449/can-i-show-hide-a-view-model-element-with-data-annotations-based-on-a-condition)
- [ASP.NET MVC: Why can't I set ShowForEdit model metadata with an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013051/asp-net-mvc-why-cant-i-set-showforedit-model-metadata-with-an-attribute)

Given the following viewmodel

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [PreventRendering]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

for which the PreventRendering attribute is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PreventRenderingAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.ShowForDisplay = false;
        metadata.ShowForEdit = false;
    }
}
```

I have a simple controller returning an instance of the ProductViewModel to a view.  The view was generated using the default Visual Studio "Add View" behavior for which I selected to be strongly typed with the ProductViewModel and I specified Edit as the scaffold.

The view displays the contents of the view model's Name using the following lines:

```
    <div >
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
```

Despite the Name property being decorated with the PreventRendering attribute, the Name property is still displayed as both editable and non-editable in the view.  Since the custom attribute implements IMetadataAware and sets both ShowForDisplay and ShowForEdit to false, why is the Name property still rendered in the view?  My reading of the documentation is the attribute provides additional metadata to prevent the rendering of the Name property in this for display and editing (when using stock Razor syntax).  What am I missing with respect to using a custom attribute in this manner?

Ultimately, I need to be able to render different properties of a view model depending on the situation and using a custom attribute that implements IMetadataAware seems (again, based on documentation) to be one acceptable way to do this in MVC4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is old but is still relevant today (MVC 5.2.2). I have been searching and exploring why this is happening and I can share what I have found so far.

It does not seem to work with EditorFor and DisplayFor helpers, still looking into why that is but, it is definitely a bug since it works fine when using EditorForModel() and DisplayForModel() helpers.

If you only need to use those helpers to create your views, your custom attribute will behave the way it is intended.